# Hair physics and/or particle edit with particles rendered as objects

Tags: particles, physics, hair

I'm trying to make a creature with feathers and therefore will be rendering hair particles as an object. However, I would like the particles to be able to be combed/ react to gravity ect. It seems like you can only do such things when the hair particles are rendered as strands. Is that true?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Figured it out, I've just got to bake the simulation before I change the render type to object.